Can't repoduce call stack in one of my programs
I'm encountering an issue while working with my application. I suspect that the version running in production might not be fully aligned with the version in my repository, but I'm not entirely sure.
Every day, I receive an email summary that includes the following call stack:
2024-09-17 13:15:06.697 +02:00 [Warning] Error parsing filename parts for file "C:\temp.txt".
System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'CHCR' was not found.
   at System.Enum.TryParseByName(RuntimeType enumType, ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnFailure, UInt64& result)
   at System.Enum.TryParse(Type enumType, ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnFailure, Object& result)
   at System.Enum.TryParse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnFailure, Object& result)
   at Application.GetFileNameParts(String file) in C:\Application\FileResolver.cs:line 229

However, when I review the GetFileNameParts method in my code (via IL Spy), I don’t see any explicit call to System.Enum.TryParse. The code only calls System.Enum.Parse, which is what I expect. Below is the relevant code snippet:
try {
    FilePart fileParts = new();
    string messageType = "CHCR";
    fileParts.MessageType = (FileMessageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FileMessageType), messageType, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    _log.LogWarning(e, "Error parsing filename parts for file {file}.", file);
    return null;
}

I’m struggling to understand how System.Enum.TryParse is appearing in the stack trace when I’m using Enum.Parse. Could this be some version mismatch, or is there something else at play that I might be overlooking?
All details which I have provided are in section above.

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs,583

While you're hitting the catch, you have a Parse in code. the Enum.Parse is using internally an TryParse (edit, as you can see in the doc provided by @CSharpie)

@shingo it's very clearly different already...

@YungDeiza Why did you say it's very clearly different? Isn't this question just about Enum.Parse disappeared from the call stack?

@shingo Enum.TryParse appears in the call stack when not called by the OP. Even the difference in answers shows the scenarios are different.

Enum.Parse calls Enum.TryParse.
See sourcecode of .NET.
The body of Enum.Parse is probably inlined by the compiler and does not appear on the callstack.

Thanks for letting me know. Is there a way to reproduce this behavior on my local machine (inlining)? I tried to build solution in Release mode but not luck of inlining that method. Call stack always appears as - method calling > Enum.Parse > Enum.TryParse.

@FlameHorizon a release build will help. Also read up on PGO (eg. here).

After further tests I can confirm that this particular method was JIT, I was able also to reproduce this behavior on my test code. Unfortunately, since this question was closed (thanks SO...) I can't post detailed explanation how to reproduce this.

Call to Enum.Parse was JITed not because of try/catch block but because of loop which contained that try/catch and call to Enum.Parse. Without the loop, Enum.Parse is not optimized.

In my setup, if I run even more iterations on Enum.Parse (like 5000), call stack is even further reduced by skipping a call to System.Enum.TryParseInt32Enum and calling System.Enum.TryParseByName directly.
